# MS Access to Snowflake - Multiple Tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to connect to Snowflake from MS Access using the Snowflake ODBC driver. After connecting I noticed multiple instances of the same table (e.g schema_name.commodity_dim, schema_name.commodity_dim){in Snowflake the schema reflects 1 instance of the table}. Does anyone know why MS Access is showing multiples of the same table. Note: this occurs for multiple tables {including tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA}. In the DSN I inputted the warehouse and database.
Does anyone know why multiple instances of the table displays?

Comment: Is it the same issue I found here or where is it showing duplicate tables? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/duplicate-tables-in-ms-access/207dc4be-24eb-4c9a-991d-34fe8586caec

Comment: It is showing duplicate tables when I link the tables in MS Access. I read somewhere that it is showing the tables in other databases that have the same "schema.table". My role in Snowflake has access to many databases. This item can be closed.